# How do I use a Squirrel Snare to trap squirrels?

Tags: neo-scavenger

I just made a couple squirrel snares, but I can't find how to use them. Consuming doesn't do anything, nor does leaving them on the ground for a bit.

Comment: Do you have the Trapping skill?

Comment: @fbueckert - Yes, you can't make the snares without it.

Comment: @SaintWacko It is possible to find a snare as loot - I did that in my first game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, just figured it out. If you scavenge a forest with a squirrel snare in your inventory, you will have the option to use it when scavenging.